# How can I create a file with utf-8 in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I use `open('test.txt', 'w')` to create a new file and its character set is **binary**.

```
>>> open('test.txt', 'w')
<open file 'test.txt', mode 'w' at 0x7f6b973704b0>

$ file -i test.txt.txt 
test2.txt: inode/x-empty; charset=binary
```

Assign a file with the specified character set (say `utf-8`) using the module `codecs`. However, the charset is still **binary**.

```
>>> codecs.open("test.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
<open file 'test.txt', mode 'wb' at 0x7f6b97370540>

$ file -i test.txt 
test.txt: inode/x-empty; charset=binary
```

I write something to `test.txt` and the charset is **us-ascii**.

```
>>> fp. write ("wwwwwwwwwww")
>>> fp.close()

$ file -i test.txt 
test.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

OK, now, I write some *special* characters (say `Arènes`). However,

```
>>> fp = codecs.open("test.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
>>> fp.write("Arènes")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 688, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

To be more specific, I would like to save the query result (using `python-mysqldb`) into a file. The key source codes are as follows:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM agency")

# Write to a file
with open('test.txt', 'w') as fp :
    for row in cur.fetchall() :
        s = '\t'.join(str(item) for item in row)
        fp.write(s + '\n')
```

Now, the charset of `test.txt` is **iso-8859-1** (some French characters, such as `Arènes`).

Thus, I use `codecs.open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')` to create a file. However, encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./overlap_intervals.py", line 26, in <module>
    fp.write(s + '\n')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 688, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**How can I create a file with utf-8 in Python?**

Comment: Your file is empty. What do you expect?

Comment: Try adding some entries into it and check.

Comment: @Tichodroma @Anand S Kumar, I write something to this file. However, the charset is `us-ascii`, not `utf-8`.

Comment: Write some Unicode characters that actually would require UTF-8.

Comment: ASCII is enough for `wwwwwwwwwww`, use something like `äöü€ÄÖÜ` as the string. See my answer below how to write UTF8 encoded Unicode to a file.

Comment: @Tichodroma yeah, the data I write to `test.txt` contains some French characters, like `Arènes`.

Comment: Then it can not be ASCII but UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 (LATIN-1). Please include the real data you use and the output of `file` you get using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty file is always binary.

```
$ touch /tmp/foo
$ file -i /tmp/foo 
/tmp/foo: inode/x-empty; charset=binary
```

Put something in it and everything is fine.

```
$ cat > /tmp/foo 
Rübe
Möhre
Mähne
$ file -i /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Python will do the same as `cat`.

```
with open("/tmp/foo", "w") as f:
    f.write("Rübe\n")
```

Check it:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
Rübe
$ file -i /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

**Edit:**

Using Python 2.7, you must encode an Unicode string.

```
with open("/tmp/foo", "w") as f:
    f.write(u"Rübe\n".encode("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: There is an error： `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` while running `fp.write("Rübe")`

Comment: Using which Python version?

Comment: Python 2.7.6. Is it the reason that I didn't reboot my mache after installing `python-mysqldb`?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you should also specify the encoding of the write():

```py
with open("filepath", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("Arènes")
```